# How to "automise" width adaptation of div to screensize?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I basically want my webpage to be deliverable on almost any mobile device, very small screensizes included.

This already works, I'm using mediaqueries in CSS to implement different styles for displays of varying size.

However, the way I'm doing it right now feels a bit "unelegant".
See this code for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .pageStyleEdition{
       text-align: left;
       margin-left:0%;
       margin-right:0%;
       width: 80%;
  }
  .displayFlexStyle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 290px) {
   .pageStyleEdition{
      text-align: left;
      margin-left:0%;
      margin-right:0%;
      max-width: 60%;
    } 
   .displayFlexStyle{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
   }
 }
```

There's a lot of redundance here, since I'm basically just rewriting the css class over and over with different width-values for the respective screensize, and I would really  like to avoid this.
Is there any easy way to just say "if the screensize is less than X, dynamically shrink the width so that it still fits into the screen!"?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the *cascading* component of CSS: when you have styles that apply to a screen of max-width 550px, for example, it is also applicable to screens with a max-width of 290px. In that sense, your second selector can be made way simpler:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .pageStyleEdition{
       text-align: left;
       margin-left:0%;
       margin-right:0%;
       width: 80%;
  }
  .displayFlexStyle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 290px) {
   .pageStyleEdition{
      max-width: 60%;
    }
 }
```

Comment: ahhh, thanks! :=)
That makes it a lot better already. But do I conclude correctly then that having the width of an element resize automatically isn't achievable (at least through pure CSS)?

Comment: @Prolo321 It depends what "resize automatically" means: if you want it to fit it's parent size, using `width: 100%` will work. But if you have some kind of calculation/conditionals that need to be satisfied, you will have to declare them individually.

Comment: Well, I want it to fit the screens size. Is the screen part of my website? The window probably is, at least on JS side I can manipulate it, but is the window dynamically connected to the screensize? And does my CSS/HTML "know" the window as well? 

Using width 100% so far hasn't really helped. When using the feature of firefox to  resize the "screen" (in the dev tools, F12), width:100% didn't make the respective elements width shrink when I actively resized the "screen" with this tool.